# How to create 3 of 3 multisig address in Bitcoin/Litecoin lightning network

Tags: bitcoind, lightning-network

Suppose we have 3 lightning nodes and a underlying bitcoin network, we need a way to create a 3 of 3 multisig address, where one node will send some satoshis to the multisig and the 2nd node will be able to withdraw the satoshis after some time lock is over with approval of 3 nodes

Comment: If you get no help, try: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't be possible without patching a lightning node implementation and breaking the protocol. Currently payment channels are 2-2 multisig wallets. Also with the payment channel construction that we currently use such an escrow service will create a huge implementation overhead. With eltoo channels multiparty channels might become a thing but eltoo requires a Bitcoin softfork

Comment: Thanks..Is there any other way to implement 3 of 3 multisig address for micro payments(reduce the transaction fee)

Comment: You could fix the htlcs that they depend on several preimages but that would mess up the routing protocol. Maybe we could come up with a higher level protocol that allows people to collaboratively come up with a preimage / payment hash. So only if all three collaborate they could release the preimage which triggers the completion of the payment